# How to curry a function w.r.t. its optional arguments in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, currying

Suppose a function `bind` has a labelled argument, optional arguments and unlabelled arguments, and you want to define a method `m` that applies the unlabelled arguments of `bind` and returns the partially applied function, so that the user of `m` can apply the labelled or optional arguments of `bind`. How do you do this? Simply writing `method m = bind a b [...] z` causes the compiler to think that the optional arguments are omitted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The position of the optional arguments (in the function declaration or function type) is important: they are only applied implicitly when the next non-optional argument is applied.

If you want the partial application of one parameter `p` to not apply an optional parameter `?o`, put `?o` after `p` in the function declaration.

Contrast

```
# let f ?o p ~z = ();;
val f : ?o:'a -> 'b -> z:'c -> unit = <fun>
# f 1;;
- : z:'_a -> unit = <fun>  (* ?o applied *)
```

with:

```
# let f p ?o ~z = ();;
val f : 'a -> ?o:'b -> z:'c -> unit = <fun>
# f 1;;
- : ?o:'_a -> z:'_b -> unit = <fun> (* ?o not applied *)
```

If you don't want to change the definition order, or want to partially
apply all non-optional parameters, you need to explicitly capture the
optional parameters that would be implicitly passed:

```
# (fun ?o () -> f ?o 1 ~z:2);;
- : ?o:'a -> unit -> unit = <fun>
```

In case you weren't familiar with it, the `?o` syntax at call site is
very handy for this: it takes an `'a option` and does the right thing to
transparently pass an optional argument, whether applied or not, to the
callee.

I have added a last `()` parameter to preserve the property that there
is at least one non-optional argument after the optional ones. It is possible to not do this, but it gets tricky and is not advised.

Comment: In the last paragraph, is the last () parameter necessary even in the method definition?

Comment: Well, its never mandatory, but you will get a warning and not have any way to fire it implicitly (as you can't "pass the next non-optional argument" for this), so it will be like a non-optional parameter of type `option`.